# Why are energy levels in a quantum well discrete?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, nanoscience

Assuming the potential is zero in $x$- and $y$-direction and zero between $z=0$ and $z=L_z$ and infinite for $z<0$ or $z>L_z$. This means the particle is confined in a layer which is infinitely extended in $x$- and $y$-direction and has a thickness $L_z$ in $z$-direction. The energy is given by:
$$E=\frac{\hbar^2k^2}{2m}=\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}(k_x^2+k_y^2+\frac{\pi^2}{L_z^2}n_z^2)$$
Where $n_z$ is a whole number larger than $0$. As far as I understand $k_z$ is quantized but $k_x$ and $k_y$ are not and can take any value. I don't understand how this leads to discrete energy levels. There is a minimum energy given by $n_z=1$ but above that I would've thought that any energy value is possible since we can just increase $k_x$ and $k_y$ continuously.

Comment: Well, in this case the energy levels are not discrete since the momentum in $x$- and $y$-direction can have any value.

Comment: But why is it then always said that quantum wells have discrete energy levels? Or is my equation wrong for a quantum well?

Comment: Quantum wells are bounded in all three directions, nit just in one direction.

Comment: "The classic model used to demonstrate a quantum well is to confine particles, which were originally free to move in three dimensions, to two dimensions, by forcing them to occupy a planar region."

(from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_well)

Everywhere I looked it said that quantum well means only confinement in 1 direction.